Web app to share files with others so they don't get deleted
I am looking for a web application where you can upload files you want to keep, or synchronize something such as WhatsApp, Google Keep, or Google Drive.
On the sites, there are other users (which may be friends coworkers or family members developers or other users with whom you may have an affiliation).
So you put or make available your files there, stored on the server via the web application, and viewable and downloadable by yourself.
But, via the server, other users have profiles.
You know some of these users.
You may share with them your files.
When your share, the files held counter for the files is incremented.
Users may auto accept shares from some users.
When a person B in a household grabs a hold of a phone of A and deletes A's stuff from the phone or cloud, the share makes sure the file is not deleted (because, the other contact holds a copy (registered as a file count or as a count for the group of files).
Is there a safe web application that implements this mechanism?
Thanks.

Cloud storages like mega.io and similar don't suit you? You can share the link only with a certain circle of people, in addition, some allow you to maintain a contact list and manage access to files. You can see more options here: https://nafanz.github.io
